# Pixel conversion in decompiled assembly from Ghidra

Tags: c, image, assembly, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm reversing an assembly function that I believe is converting an array of pixels (RGB) or photosites (RGGB) into a final array with an original (I think) encoding made of 10bits or 12bits per pixel. My goal is to understand in terms of c/c++ operations or natural language in the context of image format conversion what is happening, and in the end name in a meaningful way the variables.

There are few operation that I do not understand such as:

In the case of 10 bits per sample (1 sample ie., R|G|B):

```
uVar7 = (int64)iVar3 / 3 + ((int64)iVar3 >> 0x3f) & 0xffffffff; // 3f = 63
int iVar4 = (int)uVar7 + (int)(uVar7 >> 0x1f); // 1f = 31
puVar1 = (uint*)((int64)outData + (int64)iVar4 * 4);
*puVar1 = *puVar1 | (*inPixel & 0x3ff) <<
    (((char)iVar3 + (char)iVar4 * -3) * '\n' + 2U & 0x1f);
```

The first two lines are considering the strongest bit (`>> 0x3f` and `>> 0x1f`); but why divide by 3 ?
why add the strongest bit ? I don't get the 4th line at all; `* -3 * '\n'` in particular, and `2U & 0x1f`: why 31 as mask ?

and in the case of  12 bits per samples:

```
uint uVar8 = *inPixel & 0xfff; // considering an array of 3 bits (likely 4 times at some point)
uint uVar5 = surfaceSizeBits + position_ >> 0x1f & 7; // 7 = b111
```

`& 7` is zeroing all but the 3 lowests bits, but why after considering the strongest bit just before ?

```
dataSizeBytes_ = surfaceSizeBits + position_ + uVar5;
iVar3 = ((dataSizeBytes_ & 7) - uVar5) * 12;
```

I don't get the purpose of `- uVar5` and then `*12`; it's possible that `dataSizeBytes` is not data size in bytes here.

```
uint uVar6 = iVar3 >> 0x1f & 0x1f;
uVar5 = iVar3 + uVar6;
iVar3 = (uVar5 & 0x1f) - uVar6;
puVar1 = (uint*)((int64)outData +
    ((int64)((int)dataSizeBytes_ >> 3) * 3 +
        (int64)((int)uVar5 >> 5)) * 4);
```

`>>3` is "dropping the 2 weakest bits" but that's all I understand here.

```
byte bVar2 = (byte)iVar3;
*puVar1 = *puVar1 | uVar8 << (bVar2 & 0x1f);
if (0x14 < iVar3) // 0x14 = 20
    puVar1[1] = puVar1[1] | uVar8 >> (0x20 - bVar2 & 0x1f); //0x20 = 32
```

Here I understand the bit operations but I can't move to a higher level.

End of 12 bits case.

For the decompiled code, I provided those definitions in order to help understanding:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
typedef long long int64;
typedef int undefined; //may be wrong, may be 1 byte (int4) instead
typedef long int32;
typedef long undefined8;
typedef int int16;
typedef int int16;
typedef short int8;
typedef unsigned short uint8;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef long code;
char LogBuffer[256];
```

The undefined* are from ghidra, I did not check yet in dynamic analysis if my translation is correct.

The decompiled code from ghidra is:
(modulo few renamings and type definitions)

```
undefined8
PixelConversionInOut
(undefined8 param_1, void* inData, void* outData, int height, int widthStride,
 int bitsPerSample, int dstBufferSize, uint* bufferResult)
{
    uint* puVar1;
    int surfaceSizeBits;
    undefined8 status;
    int iVar3;
    uint64 uVar7;
    int64 currentPosition;
    uint dataSizeBytes_;

    GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (inData != (void*)nullptr && outData != (void*)nullptr)
    {
        int heightPadding = 0;
        *bufferResult = 0;
        if (bitsPerSample == 10)
        {
            if ((height == 0x818) || (height == 0x1010))
                heightPadding = 4;
            else if (height == 0x1018)
                heightPadding = 2;
        }
        int heightPadded = heightPadding + height;
        if (bitsPerSample == 10)
        {
            currentPosition = (int64)(heightPadded * widthStride * 4);
            uVar7 = currentPosition / 3 + (currentPosition >> 0x3f) & 0xffffffff;
            *bufferResult = (int)uVar7 + (int)(uVar7 >> 0x1f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (bitsPerSample == 0xc)
            {
                surfaceSizeBits = heightPadded * widthStride * 0xc;
                dataSizeBytes_ = (int)(surfaceSizeBits + (surfaceSizeBits >> 0x1f & 7U)) >> 3;
            }
            else
                dataSizeBytes_ = heightPadded * widthStride * 4 / 2;
            *bufferResult = dataSizeBytes_;
        }
        dataSizeBytes_ = *bufferResult;
        if (dstBufferSize < (int)dataSizeBytes_)
        {
            sprintf(LogBuffer, "dstBuffer must be allocated at least %d bytes.", (uint64)dataSizeBytes_);
            status = 0x80000003;
        }
        else
        {
            if (bitsPerSample == 0x10)
            {
                memcpy(outData, inData, (int64)(int)dataSizeBytes_);
                GetCurrentThreadId();
                status = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                memset(outData, 0, (int64)(int)dataSizeBytes_);
                currentPosition = 0;
                if (0 < widthStride)
                {
                    surfaceSizeBits = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        int position_ = 0;
                        if (0 < (int64)(heightPadded - heightPadding))
                        {
                            ushort* inPixel = (ushort*)((int64)inData + height * currentPosition * 2);
                            int64 rowsRemaining = (int64)(heightPadded - heightPadding);
                            do
                            {
                                if (bitsPerSample == 10)
                                {
                                    iVar3 = surfaceSizeBits + position_;
                                    uVar7 = (int64)iVar3 / 3 + ((int64)iVar3 >> 0x3f) & 0xffffffff;
                                    int iVar4 = (int)uVar7 + (int)(uVar7 >> 0x1f);
                                    puVar1 = (uint*)((int64)outData + (int64)iVar4 * 4);
                                    *puVar1 = *puVar1 | (*inPixel & 0x3ff) <<
                                        (((char)iVar3 + (char)iVar4 * -3) * '\n' + 2U & 0x1f);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (bitsPerSample == 12)
                                    {
                                        uint uVar8 = *inPixel & 0xfff;
                                        uint uVar5 = surfaceSizeBits + position_ >> 0x1f & 7;
                                        dataSizeBytes_ = surfaceSizeBits + position_ + uVar5;
                                        iVar3 = ((dataSizeBytes_ & 7) - uVar5) * 12;
                                        uint uVar6 = iVar3 >> 0x1f & 0x1f;
                                        uVar5 = iVar3 + uVar6;
                                        iVar3 = (uVar5 & 0x1f) - uVar6;
                                        puVar1 = (uint*)((int64)outData +
                                            ((int64)((int)dataSizeBytes_ >> 3) * 3 +
                                                (int64)((int)uVar5 >> 5)) * 4);
                                        byte bVar2 = (byte)iVar3;
                                        *puVar1 = *puVar1 | uVar8 << (bVar2 & 0x1f);
                                        if (0x14 < iVar3)
                                            puVar1[1] = puVar1[1] | uVar8 >> (0x20 - bVar2 & 0x1f);
                                    }
                                }
                                position_ = position_ + 1;
                                inPixel = inPixel + 1;
                                rowsRemaining = rowsRemaining + -1;
                            }
                            while (rowsRemaining != 0);
                        }
                        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                        surfaceSizeBits = surfaceSizeBits + heightPadded;
                    }
                    while (currentPosition < widthStride);
                }
                GetCurrentThreadId();
                status = 0;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
    return 0x80000023;
}
```

Here is the original assembly but ghidra did not complain or warn about the result.

```
                 **************************************************************
                 *                          FUNCTION                          *
                 **************************************************************
                 undefined8 __fastcall PixelConversionInOut(undefined8 pa
 undefined8        RAX:8          <RETURN>                                XREF[1]:     180037b9c(W)  
 undefined8        RCX:8          param_1
 void *            RDX:8          inData
 void *            R8:8           outData
 int               R9D:4          height
 int               Stack[0x28]:4  widthStride                             XREF[1]:     180037b66(R)  
 int               Stack[0x30]:4  bitsPerSample                           XREF[1]:     180037b26(R)  
 int               Stack[0x38]:4  dstBufferSize                           XREF[1]:     180037bb8(R)  
 uint *            Stack[0x40]:8  bufferResult                            XREF[1]:     180037b19(R)  
 undefined4        EDI:4          heightPadding                           XREF[2]:     180037b62(W), 
                                                                                       180037d1e(W)  
 undefined4        EAX:4          surfaceSizeBits                         XREF[2]:     180037b9c(W), 
                                                                                       180037bd7(W)  
 undefined8        RAX:8          status                                  XREF[1]:     180037bd7(W)  
 undefined8        R10:8          inPixel                                 XREF[1]:     180037c71(W)  
 undefined4        R11D:4         position_                               XREF[1]:     180037d17(W)  
 undefined8        RDI:8          rowsRemaining                           XREF[1]:     180037d1e(W)  
 undefined8        RBP:8          currentPosition                         XREF[1]:     180037d2c(W)  
 undefined4        Stack[0x20]:4  local_res20                             XREF[2]:     180037ae0(W), 
                                                                                       180037c5c(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[0x18]:8  local_res18                             XREF[2]:     180037b21(W), 
                                                                                       180037be1(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[0x10]:8  local_res10                             XREF[2]:     180037ae5(W), 
                                                                                       180037c61(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[0x8]:8   local_res8                              XREF[4]:     180037aea(W), 
                                                                                       180037c23(W), 
                                                                                       180037c40(R), 
                                                                                       180037d27(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[-0x20]:8 local_20                                XREF[2]:     180037c14(W), 
                                                                                       180037d40(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[-0x28]:8 local_28                                XREF[2]:     180037b2d(W), 
                                                                                       180037bdc(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[-0x30]:8 local_30                                XREF[2]:     180037b34(W), 
                                                                                       180037be6(R)  
 undefined8        Stack[-0x38]:8 local_38                                XREF[2]:     180037c33(W), 
                                                                                       180037d3b(R)  
 undefined4        HASH:27f0811   heightPadded
 undefined4        HASH:5fcc647   dataSizeBytes_
                 PixelConversionInOut                            XREF[2]:     GetDecompressedData:1800384fa(c), 
                                                                                      FUN_180038630:18003875a(c)  
  180037ae0 44 89 4c 24 20     MOV          dword ptr [RSP + local_res20],height
  180037ae5 48 89 54 24 10     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_res10],inData
  180037aea 48 89 4c 24 08     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_res8],param_1
  180037aef 56                 PUSH         RSI
  180037af0 41 56              PUSH         R14
  180037af2 41 57              PUSH         R15
  180037af4 48 83 ec 40        SUB          RSP,0x40
  180037af8 41 8b f1           MOV          ESI,height
  180037afb 4d 8b f8           MOV          R15,outData
  180037afe 4c 8b f2           MOV          R14,inData
  180037b01 ff 15 29 7d        CALL         qword ptr [->KERNEL32.DLL::GetCurrentThreadId]
            9d 00
  180037b07 4d 85 f6           TEST         R14,R14
  180037b0a 0f 84 42 02        JZ           LAB_180037d52
            00 00
  180037b10 4d 85 ff           TEST         R15,R15
  180037b13 0f 84 39 02        JZ           LAB_180037d52
            00 00
  180037b19 4c 8b 94 24        MOV          R10,qword ptr [RSP + bufferResult]
            98 00 00 00
  180037b21 48 89 5c 24 70     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_res18],RBX
  180037b26 8b 9c 24 88        MOV          EBX,dword ptr [RSP + bitsPerSample]
            00 00 00
  180037b2d 48 89 7c 24 30     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_28],RDI
  180037b32 33 ff              XOR          EDI,EDI
  180037b34 4c 89 64 24 28     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_30],R12
  180037b39 41 89 3a           MOV          dword ptr [R10],EDI
  180037b3c 83 fb 0a           CMP          EBX,0xa
  180037b3f 75 21              JNZ          LAB_180037b62
  180037b41 8b ce              MOV          param_1,ESI
  180037b43 81 e9 18 08        SUB          param_1,0x818
            00 00
  180037b49 74 12              JZ           LAB_180037b5d
  180037b4b 81 e9 f8 07        SUB          param_1,0x7f8
            00 00
  180037b51 74 0a              JZ           LAB_180037b5d
  180037b53 83 f9 08           CMP          param_1,0x8
  180037b56 75 0a              JNZ          LAB_180037b62
  180037b58 8d 7b f8           LEA          EDI,[RBX + -0x8]
  180037b5b eb 05              JMP          LAB_180037b62
                         LAB_180037b5d                                   XREF[2]:     180037b49(j), 180037b51(j)  
  180037b5d bf 04 00 00 00     MOV          EDI,0x4
                         LAB_180037b62                                   XREF[3]:     180037b3f(j), 180037b56(j), 
                                                                                      180037b5b(j)  
  180037b62 44 8d 24 37        LEA          R12D,[heightPadding + RSI*0x1]
  180037b66 8b b4 24 80        MOV          ESI,dword ptr [RSP + widthStride]
            00 00 00
  180037b6d 83 fb 0a           CMP          EBX,0xa
  180037b70 75 1c              JNZ          LAB_180037b8e
  180037b72 41 8b cc           MOV          param_1,R12D
  180037b75 b8 56 55 55 55     MOV          EAX,0x55555556
  180037b7a 0f af ce           IMUL         param_1,ESI
  180037b7d c1 e1 02           SHL          param_1,0x2
  180037b80 f7 e9              IMUL         param_1
  180037b82 8b c2              MOV          EAX,inData
  180037b84 c1 e8 1f           SHR          EAX,0x1f
  180037b87 03 d0              ADD          inData,EAX
  180037b89 41 89 12           MOV          dword ptr [R10],inData
  180037b8c eb 27              JMP          LAB_180037bb5
                         LAB_180037b8e                                   XREF[1]:     180037b70(j)  
  180037b8e 41 8b c4           MOV          EAX,R12D
  180037b91 0f af c6           IMUL         EAX,ESI
  180037b94 83 fb 0c           CMP          EBX,0xc
  180037b97 75 11              JNZ          LAB_180037baa
  180037b99 8d 04 40           LEA          EAX,[RAX + RAX*0x2]
  180037b9c c1 e0 02           SHL          surfaceSizeBits,0x2
  180037b9f 99                 CDQ
  180037ba0 83 e2 07           AND          inData,0x7
  180037ba3 03 c2              ADD          surfaceSizeBits,inData
  180037ba5 c1 f8 03           SAR          surfaceSizeBits,0x3
  180037ba8 eb 08              JMP          LAB_180037bb2
                         LAB_180037baa                                   XREF[1]:     180037b97(j)  
  180037baa c1 e0 02           SHL          surfaceSizeBits,0x2
  180037bad 99                 CDQ
  180037bae 2b c2              SUB          surfaceSizeBits,inData
  180037bb0 d1 f8              SAR          surfaceSizeBits,1
                         LAB_180037bb2                                   XREF[1]:     180037ba8(j)  
  180037bb2 41 89 02           MOV          dword ptr [R10],surfaceSizeBits
                         LAB_180037bb5                                   XREF[1]:     180037b8c(j)  
  180037bb5 49 63 02           MOVSXD       surfaceSizeBits,dword ptr [R10]
  180037bb8 3b 84 24 90        CMP          surfaceSizeBits,dword ptr [RSP + dstBufferSize]
            00 00 00
  180037bbf 7e 34              JLE          LAB_180037bf5
  180037bc1 48 8d 15 30        LEA          inData,[s_dstBuffer_must_be_allocated_at_l_180b675f8]              = "dstBuffer must be allocated at least %d bytes."
            fa b2 00
  180037bc8 48 8d 0d 81        LEA          param_1,[LogBuffer]                                                = ??
            db bc 00
  180037bcf 44 8b c0           MOV          outData,surfaceSizeBits
  180037bd2 e8 bd 28 1c 00     CALL         sprintf                                                            int sprintf(char * _Dest, char *
  180037bd7 b8 03 00 00 80     MOV          status,0x80000003
                         LAB_180037bdc                                   XREF[2]:     180037c10(j), 180037d4d(j)  
  180037bdc 48 8b 7c 24 30     MOV          heightPadding,qword ptr [RSP + local_28]
  180037be1 48 8b 5c 24 70     MOV          RBX,qword ptr [RSP + local_res18]
  180037be6 4c 8b 64 24 28     MOV          R12,qword ptr [RSP + local_30]
  180037beb 48 83 c4 40        ADD          RSP,0x40
  180037bef 41 5f              POP          R15
  180037bf1 41 5e              POP          R14
  180037bf3 5e                 POP          RSI
  180037bf4 c3                 RET
                         LAB_180037bf5                                   XREF[1]:     180037bbf(j)  
  180037bf5 4c 8b c0           MOV          outData,status
  180037bf8 49 8b cf           MOV          param_1,R15
  180037bfb 83 fb 10           CMP          EBX,0x10
  180037bfe 75 12              JNZ          LAB_180037c12
  180037c00 49 8b d6           MOV          inData,R14
  180037c03 e8 f8 d9 1b 00     CALL         memcpy                                                             void * memcpy(void * _Dst, void 
  180037c08 ff 15 22 7c        CALL         qword ptr [->KERNEL32.DLL::GetCurrentThreadId]
            9d 00
  180037c0e 33 c0              XOR          status,status
  180037c10 eb ca              JMP          LAB_180037bdc
                         LAB_180037c12                                   XREF[1]:     180037bfe(j)  
  180037c12 33 d2              XOR          inData,inData
  180037c14 48 89 6c 24 38     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_20],RBP
  180037c19 e8 d2 17 1c 00     CALL         memset                                                             void * memset(void * _Dst, int _
  180037c1e 48 63 c6           MOVSXD       status,ESI
  180037c21 33 ed              XOR          EBP,EBP
  180037c23 48 89 44 24 60     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_res8],status
  180037c28 85 f6              TEST         ESI,ESI
  180037c2a 0f 8e 10 01        JLE          LAB_180037d40
            00 00
  180037c30 41 8b c4           MOV          status,R12D
  180037c33 4c 89 6c 24 20     MOV          qword ptr [RSP + local_38],R13
  180037c38 2b c7              SUB          status,heightPadding
  180037c3a 45 33 f6           XOR          R14D,R14D
  180037c3d 4c 63 e8           MOVSXD       R13,status
  180037c40 48 8b 44 24 60     MOV          status,qword ptr [RSP + local_res8]
  180037c45 66 66 66 0f        NOP          word ptr [RAX + RAX*0x1]
            1f 84 00 00 
            00 00 00
                         LAB_180037c50                                   XREF[1]:     180037d35(j)  
  180037c50 45 33 db           XOR          R11D,R11D
  180037c53 4d 85 ed           TEST         R13,R13
  180037c56 0f 8e d0 00        JLE          LAB_180037d2c
            00 00
  180037c5c 48 63 44 24 78     MOVSXD       status,dword ptr [RSP + local_res20]
  180037c61 48 8b 4c 24 68     MOV          param_1,qword ptr [RSP + local_res10]
  180037c66 49 8b fd           MOV          heightPadding,R13
  180037c69 48 0f af c5        IMUL         status,RBP
  180037c6d 4c 8d 14 41        LEA          R10,[param_1 + status*0x2]
                         LAB_180037c71                                   XREF[1]:     180037d21(j)  
  180037c71 45 0f b7 02        MOVZX        outData,word ptr [inPixel]
  180037c75 83 fb 0a           CMP          EBX,0xa
  180037c78 75 37              JNZ          LAB_180037cb1
  180037c7a 43 8d 0c 1e        LEA          param_1,[R14 + R11*0x1]
  180037c7e b8 56 55 55 55     MOV          status,0x55555556
  180037c83 41 81 e0 ff        AND          outData,0x3ff
            03 00 00
  180037c8a f7 e9              IMUL         param_1
  180037c8c 8b c2              MOV          status,inData
  180037c8e c1 e8 1f           SHR          status,0x1f
  180037c91 03 d0              ADD          inData,status
  180037c93 48 63 c2           MOVSXD       status,inData
  180037c96 4d 8d 0c 87        LEA          height,[R15 + status*0x4]
  180037c9a 8d 04 52           LEA          status,[RDX + RDX*0x2]
  180037c9d 2b c8              SUB          param_1,status
  180037c9f 8d 0c 89           LEA          param_1,[RCX + RCX*0x4]
  180037ca2 8d 0c 4d 02        LEA          param_1,[0x2 + param_1*0x2]
            00 00 00
  180037ca9 41 d3 e0           SHL          outData,param_1
  180037cac 45 09 01           OR           dword ptr [height],outData
  180037caf eb 66              JMP          LAB_180037d17
                         LAB_180037cb1                                   XREF[1]:     180037c78(j)  
  180037cb1 83 fb 0c           CMP          EBX,0xc
  180037cb4 75 61              JNZ          LAB_180037d17
  180037cb6 43 8d 04 1e        LEA          status,[R14 + R11*0x1]
  180037cba 41 81 e0 ff        AND          outData,0xfff
            0f 00 00
  180037cc1 99                 CDQ
  180037cc2 83 e2 07           AND          inData,0x7
  180037cc5 03 c2              ADD          status,inData
  180037cc7 8b c8              MOV          param_1,status
  180037cc9 83 e0 07           AND          status,0x7
  180037ccc 2b c2              SUB          status,inData
  180037cce c1 f9 03           SAR          param_1,0x3
  180037cd1 8d 04 40           LEA          status,[RAX + RAX*0x2]
  180037cd4 48 63 c9           MOVSXD       param_1,param_1
  180037cd7 c1 e0 02           SHL          status,0x2
  180037cda 99                 CDQ
  180037cdb 83 e2 1f           AND          inData,0x1f
  180037cde 03 c2              ADD          status,inData
  180037ce0 44 8b c8           MOV          height,status
  180037ce3 83 e0 1f           AND          status,0x1f
  180037ce6 2b c2              SUB          status,inData
  180037ce8 41 c1 f9 05        SAR          height,0x5
  180037cec 48 8d 14 49        LEA          inData,[RCX + RCX*0x2]
  180037cf0 49 63 c9           MOVSXD       param_1,height
  180037cf3 48 03 d1           ADD          inData,param_1
  180037cf6 8b c8              MOV          param_1,status
  180037cf8 4d 8d 0c 97        LEA          height,[R15 + inData*0x4]
  180037cfc 41 8b d0           MOV          inData,outData
  180037cff d3 e2              SHL          inData,param_1
  180037d01 41 09 11           OR           dword ptr [height],inData
  180037d04 83 f8 14           CMP          status,0x14
  180037d07 7e 0e              JLE          LAB_180037d17
  180037d09 b9 20 00 00 00     MOV          param_1,0x20
  180037d0e 2b c8              SUB          param_1,status
  180037d10 41 d3 e8           SHR          outData,param_1
  180037d13 45 09 41 04        OR           dword ptr [height + 0x4],outData
                         LAB_180037d17                                   XREF[3]:     180037caf(j), 180037cb4(j), 
                                                                                      180037d07(j)  
  180037d17 41 ff c3           INC          position_
  180037d1a 49 83 c2 02        ADD          inPixel,0x2
  180037d1e 48 ff cf           DEC          rowsRemaining
  180037d21 0f 85 4a ff        JNZ          LAB_180037c71
            ff ff
  180037d27 48 8b 44 24 60     MOV          status,qword ptr [RSP + local_res8]
                         LAB_180037d2c                                   XREF[1]:     180037c56(j)  
  180037d2c 48 ff c5           INC          currentPosition
  180037d2f 45 03 f4           ADD          R14D,R12D
  180037d32 48 3b e8           CMP          currentPosition,status
  180037d35 0f 8c 15 ff        JL           LAB_180037c50
            ff ff
  180037d3b 4c 8b 6c 24 20     MOV          R13,qword ptr [RSP + local_38]
                         LAB_180037d40                                   XREF[1]:     180037c2a(j)  
  180037d40 48 8b 6c 24 38     MOV          currentPosition,qword ptr [RSP + local_20]
  180037d45 ff 15 e5 7a        CALL         qword ptr [->KERNEL32.DLL::GetCurrentThreadId]
            9d 00
  180037d4b 33 c0              XOR          status,status
  180037d4d e9 8a fe ff ff     JMP          LAB_180037bdc
                         LAB_180037d52                                   XREF[2]:     180037b0a(j), 180037b13(j)  
  180037d52 b8 23 00 00 80     MOV          status,0x80000023
  180037d57 48 83 c4 40        ADD          RSP,0x40
  180037d5b 41 5f              POP          R15
  180037d5d 41 5e              POP          R14
  180037d5f 5e                 POP          RSI
  180037d60 c3                 RET
  180037d61 cc cc cc cc        align        align(15)
            cc cc cc cc 
            cc cc cc cc
```

I may add that it's an AMD64/Intelx64 64bits assembly for Windows 10.

Comment: I think I see at least one division implemented as a multiplication by the modular inverse plus shift. Take case the disassembler handled those correctly. If in doubt, trust the assembly code.